# Cordova based app splash screen delay doesn't work for windows 10 release

Tags: cordova, uwp, windows-10-universal, splash-screen

We are developing a cross-platform application based on Cordova. For splash screen behavior, we use this plugin ""cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version "5.0.2".

we would like the splashscreen to show for 10 seconds before fading away, but this doesn't work in Windows 10 Store app release. Following is the settings in config.xml file

```
<platform name="windows">
    <splash height="300" src="res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0xFFFFFF" />
</platform>
```

With these settings, the app just shows the splashscreen briefly and the configured values don't have any impact whatsoever.

The funny thing is the property "SplashScreenBackgroundColor" works as expected.

By following the some discussion, I also toggled the "AutoHideSplashScreen" value between true and false. But no impact either.

Does anybody have some idea how to resolve this?